# Closed Interval in $E^2$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I am currently working through Introduction to Analysis by Rosenlicht

In one of the exercises $4.30,$ he asks a question regarding a closed interval in $E^2.$ I am not sure what this means. I was under the impression that intervals referred to certain sets in $\mathbb{R}.$

Is a closed interval in $E^2$ different from a closed ball in $E^2$?

Comment: what is $E^2$ ?

Comment: 2-dimensional Euclidean Space

Answer (score 0):

Mostly interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is of the form $I_1\times I_2$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. As such a closed interval may be different from a closed ball, e.g., consider the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It can be shown that it is not of the form $I_1\times I_2$.

Comment: So, intuitively, if graphed on RxR, it would look like a rectangle rather than a circle?

Comment: that's correct. however, you can show that either of one can be inscribed into other.